# PHPEXCEL set footer on the left

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm trying to set footer on the left side on my Excel sheet using phpExcel.
I wrote this code but it didn't work :

```
$sheet->getHeaderFooter()->setOddFooter('myFooter');
```

By the way, I took a look at the [documentation](http://www.osakac.ac.jp/labs/koeda/tmp/phpexcel/Documentation/API/PHPExcel_Worksheet/PHPExcel_Worksheet_HeaderFooter.html) for the HeaderFooter Class but there is no methods to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the [PHPExcel Documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#setting-the-print-header-and-footer-of-a-worksheet) (not simply the API docs), you'll see that you need to "tag" the footer value with `&` codes to identify right/center/left sections of the footer block, as well as for style codes, and functionality like page numbering.

The code for "left" is `&L`, so:

```
$sheet->getHeaderFooter()
    ->setOddFooter('&LmyFooter');
```

Comment: @Mark Baker Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56522035/how-can-i-make-default-page-number-to-every-sheet-on-maatwebsitelaravel-excel

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHeaderFooter()->setOddFooter('myFooter');
```